# Why does Akira retain her memories of her experiences as a Selector?

Tags: wixoss

In episodes 7 and 8 of *Selector Infected Wixoss*, Akira calls Ruko and Yuzuki to an abandoned building. Akira shows them the scar that appeared on her face after her third Wixoss loss and tells them that her wish was to destroy Iona. This exchange suggests that Akira retains her memories of her experiences as a Selector.

In contrast, after Hitoe suffers three losses, she does not recognise Ruko and Yuzuki after they find her on the street. Even when she looks at her Wixoss notebook, she is unable to remember Ruko and Yuzuki. This is in accordance with Hanayo's statement that upon three losses, the Selector will lose her memories associated with being a Selector.

With this in mind, why does Akira retain her memories? Perhaps Hanayo's explanation of the loss penalties was incomplete?

Answer (score 1):

> This is in accordance with Hanayo's statement that upon three losses, the Selector will lose her memories associated with being a Selector.

That is half true; Hitoe specifically lost her memories of being a Selector. Memory loss is not a consequence of losing three battles; the consequence is that the selector in question's wish becomes corrupted.

For Hitoe specifically, this corruption involved the loss of her memories of her friends and of being a selector (as well as experiencing pain from anything that would remind her of those memories), because her wish was to make friends, and she had already done so via WIXOSS battles.

For Akira, whose wish was for Iona's modelling career to be ruined, the corruption caused her own modelling career to be ruined via a facial scar preventing her from modelling.

[Source: WIXOSS wiki](http://selector-wixoss.wikia.com/wiki/Selector_infected_WIXOSS_Episode_5)